# Solution to DeGroote's sandwiching equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Johnson [describes](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0215043) a method for finding $3\times3\times23$ matrix multiplication algorithms. One of the tools he uses is DeGroote's sandwiching equations, although the exact steps are not detailed. Here's the problem.

We are given three known $3\times3$ real valued matrices, $A$, $B$ and $C$. In DeGroote's context these matrices are equivalent to

$\overline{A}=PAQ^-1$,

$\overline{B}=QBR^-1$ and

$\overline{C}=RCP^-1$, respectively,

where $P$, $Q$ and $R$ are invertible $3\times3$ matrices. Johnson used this 'sandwiching' transformation to obtain suitable (i.e. nicer) $\overline{A}, \overline{B}$ and $\overline{C}$ matrices.

**How did Johnson do this?**

If $A, \overline{A}, B, \overline{B},C$ and $\overline{C}$ are given, how one finds $P, Q$ and $R$?